# wordpress not showing gallery images

Tags: php, wordpress

I've made a `gallery` and it's ok in editor but not working in site view , it show `shortcode` instead of images. it works before but now.. i don't know what's happened.

```
$gallery = get_post_field('post_content', 186);
echo $gallery;
```

**Post Content:**

```
[gallery link="file" ids="110,147,148,154,153,152,151,150,149,155,156,157,158,159,160,161,162,163,164,166,167,168,169,176,177,178" orderby="rand"]
```

repeat, it showing all images in editor but in site view it just show this code.
any idea what is the problem?

**result:**

```
[gallery link="file" ids="110,147,148,154,153,152,151,150,149,155,156,157,158,159,160,161,162,163,164,166,167,168,169,176,177,178" orderby="rand"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should handle shortcode :

```
echo do_shortcode($gallery);
```